# How do i get more Cipher suites available in WildFly 8

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, https, wildfly

due to the [Logjam](https://blog.digicert.com/logjam-attack/) attack i had to revisit my available cipher suites. I use WildFly 8.2 and Java 7 u67. I use [sslscan](https://code.google.com/p/sslscan-win/) to test available cipher suites. Initially i had this available:
[image]

Then i installed the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)
and got two more available:

[image]

Then i had to remove the RC4's and DHE (due to Logjam) and im left with two:

[image]

I think that two are a bit low. Then i saw on a [Mozilla website](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_configurations) and on the [OpenSSL website](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES) that there are a lot of cipher suites available.

**How can i get more cipher suites available in my enviroment (WildFly 8.2 + Java7) and how many cipher suites at least should my server provide?**

Answer (score 2):

Markus Eisele did a good write up of configuring SSL with WFLY here: 
http://blog.eisele.net/2015/01/ssl-with-wildfly-8-and-undertow.html

The additional cipher-suites can be configured on the http-listener as such:

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SSLRealm"
                    enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"
                    enabled-cipher-suites="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,..."/>
```

The recommended list of cipher suites can be taken from here: 
https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html

The default names of the ciphers and the syntax in Java/WFLY are different, there is an issue in the WFLY JIRA relating to this, but AFAICT it is still unresolved:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3330

The default list for Java 8 is here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

See also: 
[What is the correct JBoss EAP 6.0.1 cipher-suite configuration for mitigation of Logjam / weakdh.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532836/what-is-the-correct-jboss-eap-6-0-1-cipher-suite-configuration-for-mitigation-of)

Comment: Thanks alot! This helped me immensely with configuring Undertow for my Wildfly 8.2 server to get my SSL grade from B to A in www.ssllabs.com/ssltest

Comment: Glad it helped @Thermometer, goodness knows I spent enough time researching this back then for everybody!!! :-D